# CakePHP: Is it possible to insert record with pre-defined primary key value?

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP model - User - that has ties to an external corporate system. I store some data on those systems and other data locally. In my `User::beforeSave()` method, I'm trying to set an ID, send the data (with that custom ID) to my corporate systems and then, if it inserts successfully there, return true so that Cake will insert the new user record with that same ID so that I can link them later.

I can't find a way to make this happen. Is there a way to **insert** a CakePHP record with a user-specified primary key value? I'm using UUIDs so there's (effectively) no opportunity for overlap.

```
$this->data['User']['id'] = String::uuid()

try {
   $user_proxy = new CoreServicesUserProxy();

   $corp_user = $user_proxy->CreateUser (

      array (

         'user' => array (

            'UserName'     => 'myusername',

            'EmailAddress' => $this->data['User']['email'],

            'SecurityId'   => $this->data['User']['id']

         )

      )

   );
}
catch ( Exception $e ) {
   // error handling stuff
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting $Model->id along with data['User']['id']? Would it be OK if you simply insert a new user within a transaction, get the new id, call the service and if everything went fine just commit?

Comment: No, I guess I didn't do that. I thought that would force an update rather than insert if I read the docs correctly. For now, I've moved the API call to User::afterSave() and it works fine, it's just not my ideal sequence. I'll look into transactions, but I'm wondering whether I can use those while also engaging a callback.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise you have already been given some hints, but here is some code which might help.

Why not add an `external_user_id` field to your `users` table?

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    function beforeSave() {
        $ds = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('core_services');
        $externalUser = $ds->createUser($this->data);
        if (!$externalUser) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->data['User']['external_id'] = $externalUser['id'];
        return true;
    }

    function afterFind($results, $primary) {
        // handle different types of find here ('all' vs 'first' vs through relation)
        foreach ($results as &$result) {
            $result = $this->_mergeExternalUser($result);
        }
    }

    function _mergeExternalUser($user) {
        $ds = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('core_services');
        $externalUser = $ds->retrieveUser($result['external_id']);
        return am($externalUser, $user);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Honestly, the only reason is economy of effort. My first choice is to do this in as laconic a manner as possible (no extra effort, entities, etc.). If that's not possible - and it appears that it isn't - then I'll adjust in the easiest way possible. In this case, by moving the API call to the afterSave() callback, I avoid having ot manage any additional data. Not my perfect world, but it will suffice. :-) Thanks.

Comment: This question has lingered long enough that I think it's fair to assume that it just isn't possible (in 1.2.x at least). I'm going to mark this as the answer since it's a solid workaround. What I actually did was reverse the calling order - local save first, remote save second. If the remote save fails, I rollback the local save.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way - but typically you would add another column to the Users table instead and let CakePHP do it's thing with the primary key. See this [Bakery article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/iiridayn/2010/11/23/sql_insert_with_known_primarykey_from_cakephp_model_save) to know how it's done. Since it is more than a year later, this is for reference mostly. As far as I understand it, this should function well with CakePHP 1.2 as well.